# javaScript div popup not hiding on outside click

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript popup. The code is as below.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>    
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/pop-bg.png") repeat top left transparent;
    z-index: 1001;
}

#popup {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    height: 361px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 597px;
}
```

**The Script:**

```
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
    if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
    else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        PopUp('show');
    }, 0);
}
```

**The jsFiddle Link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/K9qL4/

**The Issue:**

I need to close this popup onClick outside. I am able to close it on click of submit inside.

**What I tried to make it close onClick outside?**

**The Script:**

```
function hideNow()
{
document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**The HTML Code:**

```
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' onClick="hideNow()">
```

**What actually happened?**

It closes the pop up on outside click, but also closes the pop up when I am trying to access the contents inside.

I am stuck up on this issue. Can someone guide me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some code to check if you are clicking on the wrapper. Something like this would work:

```
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' onClick="hideNow(event)">
```

You need to add `event` to your function call.

And in your JS code:

```
function hideNow(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'ac-wrapper') {
        document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

In the function you check what the `event.target` is (the element you actually clicked on). If the `id` matches 'ac-wrapper', you know you clicked on the correct element.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9qL4/2/)

Comment: Awesome .. Works perfectly fine. +1 - @putvande

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did that it worked and where was I wrong ??

Comment: Got the explanation .. Thanks again .. Just one query .. can we also add a draggable to this popup ??

Comment: Yeah that should be possible. But there are many forms and it sounds like a whole different question ;)

Comment: Lolz.. Yes.. I shall post it as a different question .. Thanks for the solution. Shall accept your answer.

Comment: Here is the new Question about draggable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737536/making-a-javascript-popup-draggable - @putvande

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method stopPropagation() of the event.

see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xWrj9/

```
 $('#popup').click(function(e){    e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Thanks Zekth, but I am not using jQuery here .. I am using pure javaScript .. Thanks for your time .. +1 for your efforts