# Making a javascript popup draggable

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript popup. The code is as below.

**The HTML:**

```
    <div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' onClick="hideNow(event)">
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <h2>Popup Content Here</h2> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
    #ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/pop-bg.png") repeat top left transparent;
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    height: 361px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 597px;
}
```

**The Script:**

```
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
    if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
    else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        PopUp('show');
    }, 0);
}

function hideNow(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'ac-wrapper') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**The jsFiddle Link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/K9qL4/2/

**The Issue:**

The above script works fine, but I need to make the popUp draggable.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some code that will do what you want. It relies only on an object called `drag` to store all its values, but you can easily alter that. The example relies on there being a div with the id of `mydiv` (a `document.write()` is used in this instance to supply that) that has a `position` attribute of `absolute` or `fixed`. You can see it in action at [Jamie](http://goj.me?&//Dragging%20an%20Object%0A%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cdiv%20id=%27mydiv%27%20style=%27background:blue;%20width:100px;%20height:100px;%20position:fixed;%27%3E%3C/div%3E%22)%0A%0Adrag%20=%20new%20Object()%0A%20%20%0Adrag.obj%20=%20document.getElementById(%27mydiv%27)%0A%0Adrag.obj.addEventListener(%27mousedown%27,%20function(e)%0A%7B%0A%20%20drag.top%20%20=%20parseInt(drag.obj.offsetTop)%0A%20%20drag.left%20=%20parseInt(drag.obj.offsetLeft)%0A%20%20drag.oldx%20=%20drag.x%0A%20%20drag.oldy%20=%20drag.y%0A%20%20drag.drag%20=%20true%0A%7D)%0A%0Awindow.addEventListener(%27mouseup%27,%20function()%0A%7B%0A%20%20drag.drag%20=%20false%0A%7D)%0A%0Awindow.addEventListener(%27mousemove%27,%20function(e)%0A%7B%0A%20%20drag.x%20%20%20%20=%20e.clientX%0A%20%20drag.y%20%20%20%20=%20e.clientY%0A%20%20var%20diffw%20=%20drag.x%20-%20drag.oldx%0A%20%20var%20diffh%20=%20drag.y%20-%20drag.oldy%0A%20%0A%20%20if%20(drag.drag)%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20drag.obj.style.left%20=%20drag.left%20+%20diffw%20+%20%27px%27%0A%20%20%20%20drag.obj.style.top%20%20=%20drag.top%20%20+%20diffh%20+%20%27px%27%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

```
document.write("<" + "div id='mydiv' style='background:blue; width:100px;"
  "height:100px; position:fixed;'>" + "<" + "/div>");

var drag     = new Object();
drag.obj = document.getElementById('mydiv');

drag.obj.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e)
{
    drag.top  = parseInt(drag.obj.offsetTop);
    drag.left = parseInt(drag.obj.offsetLeft);
    drag.oldx = drag.x;
    drag.oldy = drag.y;
    drag.drag = true;
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function()
{
    drag.drag = false;
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e)
{
    drag.x    = e.clientX;
    drag.y    = e.clientY;
    var diffw = drag.x - drag.oldx;
    var diffh = drag.y - drag.oldy;

    if (drag.drag)
    {
        drag.obj.style.left = drag.left + diffw + 'px';
        drag.obj.style.top  = drag.top  + diffh + 'px';
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: ok I shall try this script and check whether it works for me .. Thanks for your time .. +1 for the efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Use the

```
.draggable();
```

jquery function, here is your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9rQK/

If you don't want to use jQuery, you should read this subject: [Draggable div without jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui)

Comment: I'm not sure if OP wants to use jQuery as his fiddle is pure javascript.

Comment: Thanks Superdrac, but I am not using jQuery here .. I am using pure javaScript .. Thanks for your time .. +1 for your efforts

Comment: pure javascript === re-inventing the wheel, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is no solution that handles the popup window
> draggable exactly as OP asked, here is one. The closes
> solution available here adds a new element to the OP's document which is dragable,
> not the popup.

## Features:

- Uses the document's `mousemove` event to re-position the popup.
- Prevents the popup from leaving the document boundary.
- Prevent the `mousedown` events to propagate from child input elements.

## Code:

```js
let dragPopup = false;
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
  if (hideOrshow == 'hide') {
    document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');

    // Placing the popup in the center middle of the screen;
    const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    popup.style.top = `${(document.documentElement.scrollHeight / 2) - (popup.offsetHeight / 2)}px`
    popup.style.left = `${(document.documentElement.scrollWidth / 2) - (popup.offsetWidth / 2)}px`
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    PopUp('show');
  }, 0);

  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");

  popup.onmousedown = (e) => {
    dragPopup = true;
    mouseX = e.pageX - popup.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - popup.offsetTop;
    popup.classList.add("drag");
  }

  popup.onmouseup = () => {
    dragPopup = false;
    popup.classList.remove("drag");
  }

  document.onmouseup = () => {
    dragPopup = false;
    popup.classList.remove("drag");
  }

  document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    if (dragPopup) {
      if (e.pageX - mouseX + popup.offsetWidth > document.documentElement.scrollWidth) {
        popup.style.left = `${document.documentElement.scrollWidth - popup.offsetWidth}px`;
      } else if (e.pageX - mouseX >= 0) {
        popup.style.left = `${e.pageX - mouseX}px`;
      } else {
        popup.style.left = `${0}px`;
      }
      
      if (e.pageY - mouseY + popup.offsetHeight > document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
        popup.style.top = `${document.documentElement.scrollHeight - popup.offsetHeight}px`;
      } else if (e.pageY - mouseY > 0) {
        popup.style.top = `${e.pageY - mouseY}px`;
      } else {
        popup.style.top = `${0}px`;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Disabling mousedown event to propogate from input child elements to avoid unnecessary drags.
  for (const child of popup.getElementsByTagName("center")[0].children) {
    // Except if child is h2 element
    if (child.tagName === "INPUT") child.onmousedown = (e) => e.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function hideNow(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'ac-wrapper') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ac-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: cacl(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1248762159/video/pop-up-circle-animation-background.jpg?s=640x640&k=20&c=4jogwiqXww2UG7s4N5W-Us-AS4QJqqTcKMCenCtztvA=") 0% / 100% 100% transparent no-repeat scroll border-box;
  z-index: 1001;
  padding: 20px;
}

#popup {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  
  /* Changing position to absolute to make it dragable */
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}

#popup.drag {
  cursor: move;
}

#popup h2 {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' onClick="hideNow(event)">
  <div id="popup">
    <center>
      <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```